# Popup when click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple html with a button 
I subscribed to mailchimp (newsletter and forms widget)
and I got from them a code for my site that works when
you load the page.
I want the page to execute the code (open the pop up)
only when I click the button. can you help me with it?

(I feel it's kind of a easy one but I'm get a bit scared
cause it's a script code - I don't know why...)

this is my page - in the head there's the script

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com

/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-`config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>`

<script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us7.list-manage.com","uuid":"d5b6774fb8bf432d69df52d93","lid":"3ed431a3b6"}) })</script>


</head>
<body>

<button type="button">Click Me!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

also, 
I upload it to a server - so this is the page online:
http://judamenahem.com/popuplp2/popup.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add to the onClick of the button the code which is in the head who load the current popup.

```
function myFunction() {
    require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us7.list-manage.com","uuid":"d5b6774fb8bf432d69df52d93","lid":"3ed431a3b6"}) });
 }
```

and use :

```
 <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: first of all - thanks.

I'm trying to follow your instructions
but still doesn't work for me. here is link to pen code:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVgVEe

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard popup boxes (those boxes that most sites use for: "Hey, you won X, do you really want to leave?") to ask the person a question via alert().

Here is some documentation on them. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp
You would simply need to attach a ClickEventHandler onto your button in your JS that triggers alert().

Comment: please notice that there is a special pop up in the page.
the thing that get me confuse is that the pop up is in a script.
I modified it a bit so it will be more clear   
so I have it a bit hard to put it inside a function - 
function {
    <script ......></script>
}
?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
```

So when you Click on Submit button then it open alert box

Comment: please notice that there is a special pop up in the page.
the thing that get me confuse is that the pop up is in a script.
I modified it a bit so it will be more clear  - notice to the second script - it is making the pop up and the question is actually how can I put it inside a function.
so I have it a bit hard to put it inside a function - 
function {
    <script ......></script>
}
?

Comment: thanks, 
I cant make it work with my script code inside the function / :

Answer (score 0):

There is also [prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) function, which lets the user interact with the box

Comment: Ok. can u help me with making it to a code - 
cause I'm a bit confuse over here and also new

Comment: I update it for the pop up I want to load
but it doesn't work.../ :
can you take a look(?):
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVgVEe

thanks, yehuda

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.organicweb.com.au/19561/wordpress/mailchimp-popup-instructions/) and [this](http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/add-a-signup-form-to-your-website) pages are any help to you